# Difference between euler and matrix animation via python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

I am trying to create an animation that rotates the object around the global Z axis.

```
obj.location=(0,0,0)
obj.rotation_euler[2]=math.radians(175)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=0)

obj.rotation_euler[2]=math.radians(185)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=10)
```

and

```
obj.matrix_world=mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(175),4,'Z')
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=0)

obj.matrix_world=mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(185),4,'Z')
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler",frame=10)
```

These 2 animations look like completely different animations.

So how can I avoid this? And why does this happen?